# Redirect does not work in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redirect, spring-boot

I have a controller, that I simply want it to redirect the request to another page. However instead of redirecting, it prints out `redirect:/test.html`.

I have tried to access `test.html` manually, and it works fine through `localhost:8080/test.html`

Here is the controller code:

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
    private String entry(){
        return "redirect:/test.html";
    }
```

Comment: check URL pattern correctly. Is test.html path is /test according to your controller file path.

Comment: I've just created a simple SpirngBoot app and it will redirect correctly if your html is at `resources/templates/test.html`. It does not required the redirect prefix as I was expecting. [Serving Web Content](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this annotation to the main class `@SpringBootApplication` it will autoconfigure your Spring Boot application. The example

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html) says

> Many Spring Boot developers always have their main class annotated
>   with `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and
>   `@ComponentScan`. Since these annotations are so frequently used
>   together (especially if you follow the best practices above), Spring
>   Boot provides a convenient `@SpringBootApplication` alternative.

You can find working example and tutorial that uses redirection from the product controller [here](https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-web-application-part-4-spring-mvc/).

Comment: I found out the issue, the problem was `@RestController` which I had to use `@Controller`

Comment: The code I've used in fact using `@Controller` annotation on mapping classes.

Comment: Yeah sorry to waste your time with my silly mistake, took me an hour to find the issue

Comment: I have updated the answer with the link for further clarification and learning.

Answer (score 0):

Config a InternalResourceViewResolver

```
@Bean
InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolverRegistry() {
    return new InternalResourceViewResolver();
}
```